# Image resize do not display the correct image in opencv python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am using Opencv 4.1.0 with python 3.

I resized a 480 X 640 size original image to 500 x 500 that works fine.

Again resized the 500 X 500 image to 25000 X 1 . I am doing this for the purpose of facial recognition using PCA.

Again when I resized the image from 25000 X 1 to  500 X 500 , it did not display the 500 X 500 image . It instead displayed a error output of black and white vertical lines.

Can someone please point out what is going wrong here ? Thanks in advance.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
image=cv2.imread('C://Users//raghu//Documents//Faces//gt_db//unique//IMG1.jpg',0)
I1=cv2.resize(image,(500,500))
I2=cv2.resize(I1,(25000,1))
I3=cv2.resize(I2,(500,500))
cv2.imshow('480x640',image)
cv2.imshow('25000X1',I2)
cv2.imshow('500x500',I1)
cv2.imshow('2-500X500',I3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Resizing to I1 works fine.Expecting the output of I3 same as I1.

Comment: That is to be expected. When you resize to 1 row or column, you lose information, which cannot be recovered by resizing larger again.

Answer (score 2):

By downsizing to 1 pixel you loose nearly all image information as all y-pixels get interpolated to a single number per x-pixel. By resizing back that pixel is then copied vertically to 500px, so I expect you to get a stripy pattern.

You should not resize, you have to reshape. That means putting the pixel values from a 2d array to a 1d array, that is what the PCA algorithm expects.

Example:

```
# create 2d array
y = np.array(range(9)).reshape(3,3)
print(y)
```

> [[0 1 2]
>   [3 4 5]
>   [6 7 8]]

```
# reshape to 1d
x = y.reshape(-1)
print(x)
print(x.shape[:2])
```

> [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
>   (9,)

[reshape documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html?highlight=reshape#numpy-reshape)